# Common LISP function for calculate numbers and ignoring letters

Tags: common-lisp

I need to write for school a function that can calculate numbers and ignore the letters. Do I need to make a case for every operation? I don't know how to start.  For example:

```
(+ 1 A 2 X) = (3 A X)
(- A 5 1 A) = 4
(* 2 C 0)   = 0
```

So I have done a part of the problem. The 2 functions DELNUM and DELSYM are for deleting the numbers respectively the symbol from a list. It's all working now, just for example like (- A 5 A) -> 5 isn't, because I need some conditions for that.

```
(defun delnum (l)
  (remove-if-not #'symbolp l))

(delnum '(4 S 56 h ))
;;-> (S H)

(defun delsym (l)
  (remove-if-not #'numberp l))

(delsym '(+ a 1 2 3 b))
;;-> (1 2 3)

(defun test (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((case (car l)
       (+ (cons (apply #'+ (delsym l)) (delnum (cdr l))))
       (- (cons (apply #'- (delsym l)) (delnum (cdr l))))
       (* (cond ((eql (apply #'* (delsym l)) 0) 0)
                ( t (cons (apply #'* (delsym l)) (delnum (cdr l))))))
       (/ (cond ((eql (car (delsym l)) 0)  '(error division by zero))
                ((eql (find 0 (delsym l)) 0) '(error division by zero))
                (t (cons (apply #'/ (delsym l)) (delnum (cdr l))))))))))

(test '(/ 0 ))           ;-> (ERROR DIVISION BY ZERO)
(test '(+ 1 2 A))        ;-> (3 A)
(test '(- 6 5 A C))      ;-> (1 AC)
(test '(- 1 5 A C X 0))  ;-> (-4 A C X)
(test '(* 0 5 A C))      ;-> 0
(test '(* 10 5 A C))     ;-> (50 A C)
(test '(/ 12 0 V 1 2))   ;-> (ERROR DIVISION BY ZERO)
(test '(/ S 3 7 C))      ;-> (3/7 S C)
(test '(+ -A A 5))       ;-> it gotta display 5 or (5)
```

Comment: From the Stackoverflow help: 'Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)'

Comment: You sometimes return a list and sometimes a number. If you could describe the problem more formally maybe you could have more ideas about how to solve it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why `(+ 1 A 2 X)` is `(3 A X)`, while `(- A 5 1 A)` is `- 6` rather than `(A 4 A)` (and, similarly, why `(* 2 C 0)` isn't `(0 C)`).

Comment: My suggestion is to write a macro that filters out the non-numbers from the argument positions and returns the filtered form; but, then again, I don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: So you need to code an evaluator which simplifies expressions containing variables (symbols). What should happen if you have `(/ -A A 1)`? Divide by zero?

Comment: It's just a school exercise. The professor said that the exemples need to make sense.

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time of this if you can treat all the elements uniformly.  E.g., if you can turn something like `(a 5 b 1 c -a)` into `((a 1) (unit 5) (b 1) (unit 1) (c 1) (a -1))`, (so that *everything* is a number times a symbol, where `unit` is just some special symbol) because then you could *group* by the symbol to get, e.g., `((a 1 -1) (unit 5 1) (c 1))`.  Then, for whatever operation you're doing, you can get `((a (op 1 -1)) (unit (op 5 1)) (c (op 1)))`, and then you can format that however you need to.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Just be careful about variables named `unit` ;-)

Comment: @coredump Yes, if I were solving this, I'd create a fresh value to use for that purpose.  E.g., `(defparameter *unit* (make-symbol "UNIT"))`.

Comment: @coredump But there's also the issue that while what I wrote would work for addition (and subtraction), it doesn't generalize enough to multiplication.  Turning `(* 0 2 a b b)` into `((unit (* 0 2)) (a (* 1)) (b (* 1 1)))` handles like terms first, but isn't enough;  the whole result should be 0, not `(0 a b)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor There is still an implicit `*` in front of all terms (which could be made explicit) so you could add simplification rules for 0 and 1.

Comment: @coredump Indeed.  I was just pointing out that it's more complex that it might initially appear. Symbolic algebra systems are complex things, indeed.